# I have two ImageButtons, which onClick will lead to webview. but I cant add the second Imagebutton

Tags: android-studio, imagebutton

I have two ImageButtons, which onClick will lead to webview. but I cant add the second Imagebutton. I dont know how to add it. Can anyone help me with this?

My main activity

```java
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageButton imageButton1;
    ImageButton imageButton2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        final ImageButton flipkart = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton1);
        final ImageButton amazon = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebutton2);
        flipkart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent  = new Intent(main.this, MainActivity.class);
                intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.in"));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

main xml file

```xml
 <ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/amazon"
    android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
    android:id="@+id/imagebutton1"
    android:layout_marginStart="11dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/flipkart"
    android:id="@+id/imagebutton2"
    android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imagebutton1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imagebutton1" />
```

my webview

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        WebView htmlWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        htmlWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
        WebSettings webSetting = htmlWebView.getSettings();
        webSetting.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSetting.setDisplayZoomControls(true);
        htmlWebView.loadUrl("url");
    }


class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

webview xml

```xml
<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/webView">

</WebView>
```

Answer (score 0):

More specific details about what you exaclty want to do be helpful,
It be helful if your will send you full code (at least your main xml) as well
you want to make your second imagebutton to work when you click ? or you want to add to your layout\screen ?
if you wahnt the second imagebutton to wark as well you ca try :

```
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent  = new Intent(main.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.amazon.in"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    flipkart.setOnClickListener(listener);
    amazon.setOnClickListener(listener);
```